# Deception to defeat an agenda

Tags: halacha, chasidut-hasidism, chinuch-education, sheker-false

The local daycare affiliated with a major chassidic group will only take a child if the parents commit to having the child continue in the group's school.

Is one allowed to knowingly deceive the daycare to ensure a spot?

---

<sup>[I am not very happy with the formulation of this question. Please edit!]</sup>

Comment: How's this formulation: May I lie to trick others into giving me stuff?

Comment: @DoubleAA :-) How about something like: May a Jewish educational institution refuse children if their parents will not commit to letting the children continue in that chassidus' school?

Comment: @DoubleAA Some people will use foil products once, then _toivel_ them to use them again, while claiming to Hashem that they changed their mind from single to multiple use. May one use similar trickery towards people?

Comment: So what you actually mean to ask is: If I'm willing to lie to my Creator then is lying to a random human any worse?

Comment: "How's this formulation: May I lie to trick others into giving me stuff?" @DoubleAA you mean "selling me stuff at the same fair price they sell it to others at", I think.

Comment: @msh210 That would also be a formulation, but I didn't mistakenly not use it while meaning to.

Comment: How is the commitment done? In writing? Your word? How can anyone commit to things that are beyond their control? Suppose one moves to a different city? Suppose the child requires remedial tutoring and the school can not help this child?

Comment: @GershonGold I guess they would take your word for it and accept losses, but the agenda is obvious: Our resources for our kids. Is such an agenda halachically acceptable?

Comment: "Is such an agenda halachically acceptable?" is a different question than "Is one allowed to knowingly deceive the daycare to ensure a spot?" It can be that the agenda is unacceptable and you still may not be allowed to knowingly deceive. Or it can be that the agenda is acceptable and you still may be allowed to deceive. Your question truly requires clarification.

Comment: Also I do not see why it matters whether it is a major Chassidic group or if it is a private individual?

Comment: @NBZ if [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34140/deception-to-defeat-an-agenda#comment87487_34140) is the question you really mean to ask, why not ask that?

Comment: Can somebody put this on hold until we get an answer to [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34143/commiting-to-a-groups-educational-system)?

Comment: Putting on hold by request of asker (and because I was tempted to anyway).