# Commiting to a group's educational system

Tags: halacha, tzibur-community, chinuch-education

In a community where spaces are scarce in educational institutions, may a Jewish institution  refuse a child if the parents will not commit to letting the child continue in that group's separate privately funded school?

The institution will gain economically from each child that is there.

Let us assume the institution would take the parents' word for it and accept any losses, while the agenda is obvious: The groups wants to reserve any empty spaces are for its own children.

Comment: I would assume they can do whatever they want with their resources, so long as they aren't using it for sin or just throwing it out.

Comment: @DoubleAA Better?

Comment: Adderabba. Now it's a question of government policy, not just halacha.

Comment: @DoubleAA Okay, added that tag too.

Comment: Problem is, I'm not aware of any government nowadays whose policies are on topic here.

Comment: @DoubleAA The point would be that the group is not loosing money (they are in fact gaining), but they want to reserve _availability_ to their group's children.

Comment: Whatever the point is, if it is on topic, you may ask it if you can figure out how to put your query into English.

Comment: @DoubleAA Should I remove the tag then?

Comment: Who're "you" and what "word" do "you" give? Anyway, this question smells like a request for [_p'sak_](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: @msh210 I cannot answer that since the question is theoretical – not a request for p'sak. (I wouldn't send my child to such a place anyway.) When someone mentioned the situation, I got curious and thought of asking כ"ק אדמו"ר מי יודע.

Comment: I meant that the question is unclear. It starts off asking what an institution may do to a child and his or her parents, and then says "they would take your word for it". "[T]hey" I assume means the institution, but who are "you", and what is this "word" to which you refer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about government policy, rather than about halachah or Jewish values.

Comment: @Chanoch Better?

Answer (score 0):

If money is given good naturedly to an institution on the understanding that it will be distributed evenly and good naturedly, and it isn't, then the instutution has embezzled the funds provided to it as they have not used the money for its intended purpose.

Comment: How do you know this?